# pointer assignment in textbook

Tags: c++, pointers

In my c++ textbook, the following code crops up:

```
B * pointerToB = new B();
A * pointerToA = pointerToB();
```

I'm quite familiar with pointers but what's confusing me is the parentheses at the end of the second line. I've never seen it done this way before. I was expecting something more like:

```
A * pointerToA = &(*pointerToB);
```

I've scoured my textbook for an explanation but came up short. Ultimately, I've concluded that

```
A * pointerToA = pointerToB(); // is synonymous with
A * pointerToA = &(*pointerToB); // this line
```

And here are the implementations for classes A and B:

```
class A {
public:
 A (): dataOne(2){}
 virtual void whoAmI(){printf("class A");}
private:
 int dataOne;
};

class B : public A {
public:
 B (): dataOne(4){}
 virtual void whoAmI(){printf("class B");}
private:
 int dataTwo;
};
```

Is my reasoning sound?

Comment: No. It's a pointer to an object of class B.

Comment: I guess that's a mistake in your book. `pointerToB()` is a function call, doesn't make sense on a pointer.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm thinking...

Comment: Maybe you can provide some info on the types A and B?

Comment: Yeah, it's gotta be a mistake then... The time I wasted over this issue!.. Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: A and B are basically just classes with one or two data fields. It was a part of the book explaining the slicing problem.

Comment: A and B were very small classes meant solely for example.

Comment: "*`A * pointerToA = &(*pointerToB)` Is my reasoning sound?*"  That is valid, but no different than `A * pointerToA = pointerToB` ... (nudged by @DyP)  ... for the types likely to be in your textbook.  :)

Comment: A is no base class of B?

Comment: @DrewDormann If there's no operator overloaded, yes.

Comment: The implementations are up.

Comment: So yeah, I'm guessing it was a mistake on my book's part... :\